# Os blocos de código irão ficar com font-size igual a 12?

Tags: debate, bug, status-nãorepro, design

Notei que reduziram o tamanho da fonte dos blocos de código para 12. Não sei se preciso de óculos, mas a leitura está difícil. Essa mudança é permanente ou é um bug?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Esse tamanho foi alterado para mim hoje, *16 de maio de 2014*, no entanto parece que outros usuários já estavam utilizando o tamanho reduzido a tempo.

Comment: Nunca gostei disto também e já reclamei em algum lugar. Mas acabei acostumando depois de tanto tempo.

Comment: @bigown ficar lendo um código com fonte de tamanho 12 e com background cinza não tem como, até ontem estava normal, pensei que fosse até um bug, assim fica complicado.

Comment: Mudou recentemente? Então não é o mesmo problema relatado [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188/tamanhos-de-fontes-botoes-e-formatacao-css-maior), certo?

Comment: @bfavaretto sempre esteve com o tamanho legível, creio que 14, hoje eu entrei e o tamanho da fonte está diferente, está menor do que o normal, tamanho 12 agora. Não entendi. Em relação ao link que você colocou estou mais confuso ainda, porque o tamanho já estava 12 a muito tempo, mas pra mim estava 14 e mudou hoje pra 12, estranho isso, e está inviável continuar lendo nesse tamanho, vista cansada, não dá mesmo.

Comment: Eu também estou confuso. Será que estão fazendo A/B testing com a gente?

Comment: @bfavaretto de madrugada antes de acontecer isso comigo o site estava "apenas para leitura", não podia realizar o login e interagir. Provavelmente essa manutenção que alterou a forma como visualizo, pode ter sido isso.

Comment: Acho que não, aquilo foi queda de energia no datacenter (!) http://stackstatus.net

Comment: O novo tamanho fica melhor do que o anterior quando visualizado no Safari/OS X. Por outro lado, texto formatado com acento grave em linha, no meio de texto normal, ainda está em fonte maior (14px), destoando do restante do texto.

Comment: Aqui nunca mudou, desde que eu conheço o site.