# Votação para alterações de layout

Tags: debate, layout

Dê um *upvote* na resposta em que você concorda com a mudança

Dê um *downvote* se você não concorda

**Obs**.: vocês também podem propor mudanças

---

## Atualização 11/06/2014

Há uma semana que esta votação está aberta

Seis tópicos tiveram saldo positivo:

1. Adição de "Procurando um emprego?"

   > +18
   >   -2
2. Maior destaque na cor dos *links* já visitados em relação ao texto

   > +7
   >   -0
3. Subir o max-width: das imagens para 640px

   > +5
   >   -0
4. Ajustar espaço antes dos títulos

   > +5
   >   -1
5. Corrigir *bug* da barra lateral

   > +3
   >   -0
6. Trocar "visto" por uma tradução melhor

   > +3
   >   -1

Agora está na mão dos administradores decidirem se e quais alterações serão de fato implementadas (e implementá-las, claro).

Comment: +1 por ter levantado a discussão

Comment: Relacionada: [Tamanhos de Fontes, Botões e Formatação CSS maior](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1188/3117)

Comment: Realmente acho que precisamos mudar um pouco o layout, adicionando itens como o sugerido pelo @Andrey em uma das respostas

Comment: Caberia aqui o uso da tag `novo-recurso`? (já que agora não estamos mais apenas debatendo, e sim pedindo que algo seja feito)

Comment: Se você acha o certo @mgibsonbr, se sinta a vontade para editar a pergunta. Eu não editei pois não tenho certeza.

Comment: Tem uma coisa aqui que me incomoda desde quando a pergunta foi postada originalmente: não é um debate (ou novo-recurso), mas vários. Difícil os devs resolverem o pacote todo de uma vez. Talvez seja necessário desmembrar em feature-requests separados.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tirou as palavras da minha boca! Eu também estava incerto, pelo formato da pergunta (i.e. o que está sendo pedido de fato está *nas respostas* - ainda que a pergunta faça referência pra elas), por isso perguntei. Concordo com sua sugestão.

Answer (score 24):

Adição de "Procurando um emprego?"

(Talvez a maior visibilidade estimule o interesse das empresas em oferecer mais vagas no Brasil e Portugal)

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 interessante pelo motivo fornecido.

Comment: +1 por abrir oportunidade a programadores que estão ocupados de mais para procurar um emprego melhor

Comment: 10 pessoas estão procurando por emprego e votaram a favor dessa resposta

Answer (score 13):

### Maior destaque na cor dos links já visitados em relação ao texto.

A cor atual dos visitados praticamente some quando [colocada no meio do texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1482/70). Aqui ainda aparece um pouquinho mais do que no SOpt "não meta".

Lembre que se pra você aparece bem destacado, pode ser diferença de calibração de monitor. O meu precisa estar calibrado razoavelmente bem, pois também edito imagens. E fica realmente morto o link aqui.

Comment: Como um remendo eu costumo por em negrito, ou escrevo textos intuitivos no link como "CLIQUE AQUI!!!". De fato isso deve ser melhorado.

Comment: Concordo, links no SO são bem apagados.

Comment: Aparentemente além da melhoria nas cores, o sublinhado resolveu.

Answer (score 9):

### Subir o max-width: das imagens para 640px

Aqui é 630px apenas. No SOzão o max-width é 640px.

São dois sites separados, mas manter a consistência dos dois ajuda a "reciclar" imagens na tradução dos posts, ou mesmo criar novas para fazer cross-posting. As de 640px cabem perfeitamente no SOpt sem mexer no resto da página, não vejo motivo para as nossas terem esta "economia" de 10px.

(Descobri isso justamente por ver que uma imagem no SOzão estava ok, e aqui a mesma distorceu um pouco, em certa ocasião)

Comment: aparentemente o limite continua.

Answer (score 6):

### Ajustar espaço antes dos títulos:

Veja a explicação e o problema "ao vivo" aqui mesmo:

### Motivo:

O título "Motivo", por exemplo, está muito próximo do bloco de cima. Por lógica teria que ser mais espaçado do de cima do que deste bloco de texto aqui <==.

### Simulação da solução.

Neste título usei um <br> para descolar o "Simulação" do bloco de cima. Faz mais sentido o espaço maior, não? Não precisa ser tanto, claro. O importante é não precisar dessa gambiarra de <br>.

> Antes de votar nesta aqui, seja +1 ou -1, tenha a certeza de ter entendido o problema antes. Em caso de dúvida, pergunte.

Comment: Já tinha percebido isso também, mas nem lembrei de por aqui. Boa Bacco!

Comment: Complementar à essa sugestão, acho que poderia ser o caso de haver uma forma mais clara de se fazer títulos e subtítulos. Pelo visto a estilização do *markdown* aqui não distingüe **Cabeçalhos** (texto entre ##) e aquilo que melhor descrevia um subtítulo (texto sublinhado por 3 hífens). Sem esse... "apelo", só via HTML mesmo, com marcaçoes de <h1>, <h2>...

Comment: @BrunoAugusto tem o `---` e o `===`, há uma pequena diferença de tamanho de fonte entre os dois. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Conheço markdown, mas então, é tão pequena a diferença que poderia ser melhorado.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto poste como uma resposta, assim a sugestão pode ser votada como as outras. O assunto não está esgotado. E acho que poderia realmente ter uma diferença um pouco maior entre as fontes, desde que sem exagero, claro.

Comment: E o problema persiste e eu continuo colocando <br> antes dos titulos

Answer (score 5):

Corrigir bug em que a barra lateral fica sobre a barra inferior (na página de criação de uma nova pergunta):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: This is not a bug. It's a feature! [(Relacionado)](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553/lista-de-perguntas-similares-sobrepoe-footer-quando-muito-grande)

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeBernal. [Vejam aqui a diferença.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MOuDn.png)

Comment: Discordo. *Feature* seria se essa caixa ficasse escondida sem sobrepor o rodapé, expandindo-se ao parar o mouse.

Answer (score 5):

Trocar "visto" por uma tradução melhor

("visto" dá a entender que foi a última vez que alguém viu o perfil daquele usuário, sendo que na verdade a informação é sobre a última vez que aquele usuário entrou)

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ou "ativo há" 3 minutos atrás.

Comment: acho que isso entra mais como uma correção de bug de tradução do que alteração de layout, não é não?

Comment: "Ativo há" dá espaço para trocadihos engraçaralhos, i.e.: se o perfil diz "ativo há 3 dias", quer dizer que antes disso você era o passivo?

Comment: "entrou última vez" também dá pra pensar besteira, -1

Comment: @Math Sugira um melhor então...

Comment: @Math Sobre isso ser uma correção de bug... Você está falando da outra resposta, né? (A da página de criação de nova pergunta)

Comment: @Andrey sobre sugerir uma melhor, acho que "visto" está bom; sobre sua segunda pergunta, não entendi muito bem, mas o que eu quis dizer é que é possível que essa resposta aqui fosse uma "pergunta" completamente nova, me baseando nesse post: [**Sobre partes do site em inglês**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10/3117) Mas eu não tenho certeza, por isso apenas sugerir.

Comment: @Math Na verdade, cada uma destas respostas poderia ser uma pergunta diferente, só que ficaria poluído demais. Aqui alguns problemas estão centralizados.

Comment: @Andrey é que eu me apeguei ao título, que diz tratar de layouts, e ao meu ver isso é mais a correção de um bug. Não acho que esteja errado, mas na minha opinião não era o mais adequado. Sobre a outra questão, evitar poluir o site é um algo bom, mas tem um porém que não dá para os moderadores marcarem tags do tipo aceito, by-design, declinado, etc. Entretanto acho que o mais importante é levantar discussões frutíferas e depois podemos tomar ações mais direcionadas. Não precisa mudar nada, acho que no fundo tá muito bom assim.

Comment: Eu acho que essa aqui está um pouco fora das questões de layout, e devia fazer parte das várias de tradução. Acho que até já tem esse assunto em outro lugar.

Comment: Em tempo: simplesmente "atividade" talvez fosse uma boa saída.

Answer (score -4):

Aumentar a fonte dos blocos de código para facilitar a leitura e prevenir problemas de saúde:

de `12px`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para `13px`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Obs: Eu estava utilizando `13px` até pouco tempo quando foi alterado para `12px` de forma repentina. Já havia reclamado [isso aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365/os-blocos-de-c%C3%B3digo-ir%C3%A3o-ficar-com-font-size-igual-a-12).</sup>