# Pra que servem publicações "Wiki da comunidade" no Meta? Já que votos aqui não alteram a reputação

Tags: suporte, wiki-comunitário

Vendo a pergunta e as respostas do seguinte tópico:

[Votação para alterações de layout](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1464/3117)

fiquei me perguntando, será que as publicações não deveriam ter sido criadas tudo como wiki? Especialmente pois o usuário recebeu muitos votos negativos e apesar de não ser algo muito relevante, já que os votos aqui não alteram a reputação, o usuário terá vários pontos negativos nas respectivas tags da pergunta. É claro que o oposto valeria se ele tivesse dados opções bem aceitas pela comunidade, entretanto, não tenho certeza se esse seria o caso para usar wikis aqui no meta.

Talvez todas publicações de votação deveriam ser marcadas como wiki? Ou existe alguma outra regra para definir quando a publicação deve ser do tipo wiki? Qual seria essa regra?

Comment: Como o *upvote* e *downvote* não são importantes aqui, não faz grande diferença. Mas que deveria ser wiki, acho que sim.

Comment: @JorgeB. pois então, vc acha que sim, mas é baseado no _feeling_ ou baseado em alguma outra coisa mais concreta?

Comment: É mais no *feeling*, e estou habituado a ver esse tipo de questões como wiki's. Ao ver que a pergunta é marcada como wiki tenho logo outra ideia e mais vontade de ver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Há uma concepção errada para que serve o CW. Não é para tirar reputação. A CW é para **abrir mão da propriedade do post**. É para facilitar a colaboração entre usuários.Um exemplo é você responder algo que estava em um comentário mas não acha justo receber o crédito pela resposta que efetivamente não é sua.

Houve uma época no SO que a CW era usada para atender os usuários que não gostavam de ver outros usuários (não sei porque as pessoas se preocupam tanto com a reputação dos outros) ganhando reputação fácil com perguntas muito simples ou pouco úteis. Como essas perguntas passaram não ser permitidas, essa "função" contrabandeada pôde ser abandonada também. Mas o legado ficou.

Uma função legítima da CW era permitir a edição mais facilitada porque exigia menos reputação, mas hoje temos a sugestão de edição que acaba resolvendo o problema.

De fato a utilização da CW hoje ficou relegada para poucas coisas. Curiosamente faz mas sentido no meta onde podemos ter mais situações que dependemos da colaboração de todos.

No passado uma pergunta se transformava em CW depois de X (acho que é 30) respostas. E qualquer post se transformava em CW depois de Y (acho que era 10) edições. Isso nunca fez muito sentido, mas no começo parecia fazer quando o SO era mais bagunçado. Esse dia existiu.

Veja no [blog da SE](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) como ficou a CW. tem um [artigo mais antigo](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) que dá outras indicações.

É um erro achar que o meta não tem reputação. Ela apenas não é mostrada para ninguém. A reputação é usada para outros controles, de medalhas por exemplo. Mas que ninguém se preocupe com reputação no meta, ela é irrelevante, não ajuda ou beneficia alguém.

Porque alguém abriria mão da propriedade de um post? Isso é bem raro mas quando você estiver em um situação que cabe isto, você provavelmente perceberá. è uma forma de fazer algumas ações de forma mais ética. Outra forma é você querer que outras pessoas realmente mexam no seu post. Isto normalmente não dá muito certo. As pessoas preferem fazer seus posts.

Comment: `A CW é para tirar a propriedade, é para facilitar a colaboração entre usuários. Com o CW a reputação mínima para editar é menor.` acho que devemos ter isso em mente então na hora de decidir se devemos criar CWs ou não, correto? Parece que funciona bem como um guia.

Comment: Sim. Ou seja, não devemos usar CW :) É para usar bem raramente. Na pergunta da votação do on-topic eu preferi para deixar as pessoas editar a pergunta e tirar itens de lá (nem funcionou muito assim). Outro motivo é para alguém que ainda pensa que no meta é igual ao principal e achar que não deveria votar em uma resposta para não dar ou tirar reputação. Mas foi mais cuidado extra do que uma necessidade real.

Comment: Não que seja uma regra efetivamente. É uma diretriz evitar a CW porque normalmente ela não resolve nenhum problema a não ser tirar a propriedade do post de um único usuário. Hoje que a edição é possível de qualquer forma, isso só ajuda a colaboração porque ninguém vai se preocupar tanto em mexer em algo alheio (se bem que tem gente que vira coautor em alguns posts assim mesmo, não não ninguém deveria fazer mudanças profundas em posts não wiki). O melhor ponto é **abandonar a propriedade do post**.

Comment: Ok, nunca vou usar o CW então, _quando chegar a hora saberei que tenho que usar_ :) parece meio subjetivo mas blz