# Maior destaque na cor dos links já visitados em relação ao texto

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, layout, hyperlinks

### Maior destaque na cor dos links já visitados em relação ao texto.

A cor atual dos visitados praticamente some quando [colocada no meio do texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1482/70). Aqui ainda aparece um pouquinho mais do que no SOpt "não meta".

Lembre que se pra você aparece bem destacado, pode ser diferença de calibração de monitor. O meu precisa estar calibrado razoavelmente bem, pois também edito imagens. E fica realmente morto o link aqui.

*A pedido do @Bacco*

Answer (score 3):

Percebi agora a pouco no no Meta do Stack-EN os links são sublinhados:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print retirado daqui: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions

Isso dá bastante destaque para os *links*. Talvez seja uma boa ideia adotar o mesmo aqui. Eu diria não só para o Meta, mas no site principal também.

Comment: Ahauhahu, não sei o motivo, mas esse post me submeteu à mente o `text-decoration: none`. Quanto aos links, não sei se estão tão mortos assim. Aqui eles parecem bem vivos e olha que o meu monitor tem mais de 5 anos.

Comment: @Patrick A impressão que eu tenho é que eles já andaram mexendo um pouco nisso. Ainda assim acho que poderia melhorar um pouco mais.